# How to replace a textbox with current date,if the input is not a date?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a date picker on my web form .If the user gives a data other than date then I want to replace that input with the current date . For that I tried to use the following function ,but it is not working(No error / no expected result) 
**Jquery**

```
$('#datepicker1').change(function () {       
        var timestamp = Date.parse($("input[name='datepicker1']").val())
        if (isNaN(timestamp) == true) {
            var d = new Date();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = d.getDate();
            var output = (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' +
                (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear()
            $('#datepicker1').val(output);
        }
    });
```

**Design**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Joining Date</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" />
</div>
</div>
```

Hope you got the idea , am not good at jquery please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
var value=$.trim($("#datepicker1").val());

if(value.length<0)
{
  var now = new Date();
  $('#datepicker1').val(now);
}
```

Use the Date.parse() method to check if a date is valid:

```
var timestamp = Date.parse($("#datepicker1").val()) 

if (isNaN(timestamp) == false) { 
    var d = new Date(timestamp); 
    $('#datepicker1').val(d);
}
```

Comment: then make user to pick only date. add date picker in input field.

Answer (score 0):

Please check jsFiddle demo

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
var output = (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' +
    (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear()
console.log(output)
$('#datepicker1').val(output);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dhaval_123/g4nsjkLk/